# UITableViewCell imageView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have cell with style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`. So if object is new i add image if not delete that image.
I try this:

```
if (something) {
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"new.png"];
            cell.imageView.image = img;;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = nil;
        }
```

But the title and subtitle mode to left. I want that there will be white space if not new.

I make this:

```
if (something) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"new.png"];
        cell.imageView.image = img;;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(25, 38);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
        cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

25 and 38 it width and height of my image.

It work fine, maybe it is more easy way to achieve this.

I want to achive this:

---

```
 --
|  | TextLabel
 --  detailtext label

 --
|  | TextLabel
 --  detailtext label

 --
|  | TextLabel
 --  detailtext label

     TextLabel
     detailtext label
```

So cell will be straight. If not new no image but space. If new image.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? Do you want to show image with proper aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blankImage.png"];
```

on the place of

```
cell.imageView.image = nil;
```

where blankImage.png is simple white image.

Comment: Is it better than my choice?? with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. My version will be more dynamic if image will change in future from 0 to 40 size.